# How to total values in a List<t> where key values are the same

Tags: c#

I have a List that looks like this

```
List<custom> this_list = new List<custom>();

this_list.Add(new custom()
{
  key = male,
  value = 50
});

this_list.Add(new custom()
{
  key = female,
  value = 90
});

this_list.Add(new custom()
{
  key = male,
  value = 5
});
```

How would I be able to evaluate this list so I can determine that there are 55 males and 90 females? Also, let's suppose that my keyset is very large and it would be inefficient to manually define male or female or another key.  How would I create a new list containing the combined totals and unique keys?

Thanks for any help and attention!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a grouping using `GroupBy` on the gender:

```
var query = this_list.GroupBy(x=> x.key)
                     .Select(g=> new {Gender = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(x=>x.value)});

foreach(var result in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", result.Gender, result.Count);
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants `Count = g.Sum(a => a.value)` instead of the actual object count.

Comment: Thanks! This solution is working great. When we set Gender = g.Key it seems to assign x.key. How does it know that g.Key is x.key?  Does it automatically assume the first value of my list structure is a .Key?

Comment: @atwellpub: No - you told it with `GroupBy(x=> x.key)` that made it group by `key` which is mapped to the public property `Key` in the resulting grouping

Answer (score 4):

```
var results = from c in this_list
              group c by c.key into g
              select new custom(g.Key, g.Sum(x=>x.value));

//results now has two elements of the original "custom" type; 
//one male with a count of 55, one female with a count 90
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from c in this_list
group c.value by c.key into g
select new custom { key = g.Key, value = g.Sum() }
```

Comment: I think you need `g.Sum(a => a.value)`

Answer (score 2):

LINQ!

```
this_list.Where(c => c.key == male).Select(c => c.value).Sum();
```

Comment: +1, but the OP wants the count of females too (trivial; do the same thing for the other key).

Answer (score -1):

**Update: I misread the question.** I like Sam I am's answer:

```
this_list.Where(c => c.key == male).Select(c => c.value).Sum();
```

**These won't work:**

```
var maleCount = this_list.Count(item => item.key == male);
var femaleCount = this_list.Count(item => item.key == female);
```

Comment: That's actually incorrect. You want `this_list.Sum()` instead, assuming I understand the question.